# Regular expression to match nine numbers and a capital letter at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to validate nine numbers and only one capital letter after them, such as:

```
123456789A
```

The regular expression I used doesn't work for me:

```
/^[0-9]{9}.[A-Z]{1}$/
```

Could you help me to figure out a working expression?

Comment: What's the `.` supposed to do? (And `{1}` is redundant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have a dot in between your two things. Also, do you need to match the start and end of the string? If not, you may remove that(the ^ and $).

A tip is that you use http://www.regexr.com/ so you can see exactly what each token does.

So, anyways, simply remove the dot, so it looks like this:

```
/^[0-9]{9}[A-Z]{1}$/
```

This is not the most optimal solution however. To begin with, you can use the "digit flag", which is \d and add {9} to it. Then you can also remove the {1} as that is already assumed.
In the end:

```
/^\d{9}[A-Z]$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
^[0-9]{9}[A-Z]$
```

`.` is unnecessary, it's not a concatenation but it stands for "any letter excluding a newline".

`{1}` also, for sake of simplicity just `[A-Z]` is enough.

here, you also can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` but I prefer `[0-9]` because it's more explicit.

see: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bK8mC6/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
\d{9}[A-Z]
```

Matches 9 digits and 1 uppercase character

Answer (score 1):

You are close to the solution! You just don't need the point `.` operator at all:

```
/^\d{9}[A-Z]$/
```

The above expression will match any string containing nine numbers and a capital letter at the end. If you want to make it case insensitive and match any letter you can add the modifier `i` (case-insensitive). I also used the `\d` operator, which matches any digit, instead of `[0-9]`, it's shorter and easier to read.

Here's a **[working example](https://regex101.com/r/rR6aP5/1)** of the above RegExp.